# Offline MGRS Nearby

Tags: utm, grids-graticules, mgrs

Is there anyone of us here experienced to use the **Mgrs Nearby** 
http://www.nearby.org.uk/google/Gridlines_mgrs.kml.pl  in googleEarth Pro?  It is a helpful .kml specially to navigators because it displays the MGRS Grids of an area.  Meanwhile while I'm searching for an alternative way of displaying MGRS grid lines in Google Earth.  I saw this site
http://www.nearby.org.uk/blog/2007/06/19/mgrs-layer-for-google-earth-offline/
that shows how to use it offline. My problem were I can't find appweb anymore in the Internet and the tutorial was totally obsolete. Can someone help me figure it out how to implement this into other web seervers such as XAMMPP or other possible web software so that I can use it offline?

Comment: You've been here in GIS SE  a while, but still haven't taken the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. We use a "Focused question / Best answer" model, which expects a reasonable level of effort in framing the problem. You have two major questions here, and no clear problem. Please [Edit] the question.